# Determine access rights of a user in a particular role

Tags: security, accessibility

I want to fetch access rights of a user to an item who has been under a security role. I am controlling the access to that particular item by adding the user to that role. Can someone help how I can fetch the access rights of those users under a role programatically?

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
AccessRuleCollection accessRules = item.Security.GetAccessRules();
AccessRightCollection accessRights = AccessRightManager.GetAccessRights();

foreach (AccessRight accessRight in accessRights)
{
    AccessPermission accessPermission =
        accessRules.Helper.GetAccessPermission(account, accessRight, PropagationType.Entity);

    // use accessPermission value here as you wish
}
```

Don't forget to set `account` before and fill it with user you are interested in.